# Daylight saving - past dates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime

I save dates as UTC in mongoDB. I already know that date object creation converts it to the local time offset according to the user's OS settings.

But let's say that in 21 aug 2020 the local offset was +8 hours and because of daylight saving in 22 aug 2020 the offset was +9.

My question is what happens to past dates I saved in the DB. The Date object will convert it to the local time as it was in the past date or it converts to the local time as for now.

Hope I explained it well. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

UTC does not have the concept of daylight savings time. DST only applies to local times.

Therefore dates that are stored in UTC are not affected by DST in any way.

Another way of looking at it is time in UTC is always continuous.

When you are converting from UTC to local time, you need to know which *time zone* the local time is in. Time zone is not the same thing as a UTC offset - a time zone is a rather extensive set of rules and historical transitions that define exactly what time it was in that time zone at any instant in physical time.

For example, a time zone is "America/New_York". This time zone uses two UTC offsets, -4 and -5, depending on time of year, and what year it is.

Comment: First of all thank you for the detailed answer!
So if I understand correctly - when I convert the saved date it will use the historical offset and not the current offset?

Comment: I don't know what will happen in your application, the correct implementation is to use the correct offset at the time that you are converting.

Comment: The term "time zone" has changed. Originally, time zones were regions roughly defined by lines of longitude where everywhere in the zone had the same offset. But different places in the same time zone adopted different offsets at different times, then daylight saving time (DST) really made a mess of it. IANA introduced the concept of "representative location" to define a particular set of historic rules for offset and DST associated with a well known city. These have now also been colloquially called "zones", but are really locations as they have no fixed area and change from time to time.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thank you.